# How to tile very large image files

Tags: image, image-processing, imagemagick, tiff

I have got a large TIFF file (~160000x50000 px @ 3,5 GB) and I need to extract PNG tiles of 256x256 px out of it in order to overlay it on a map.

I tried ImageMagick with `magick stream -extract 256x256+xOffset+yOffset source.tif tileXXX.png` but there was no result beside my pc building a huge cache file and quit working.

How can this task be approached efficiently?

Comment: that's 8 gigapixels... probably challenging to keep that in RAM, so it better not be compressed in any inconvenient way -- https://pypi.org/project/tifffile/ and check if you can memory-map your file.

Comment: Try with `vips` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vips

Comment: ```vips``` is doing great! I used ```vips dzsave source.tif tilesFolder --depth one --tile-size 256``` and it worked like a charm.

Comment: Cool. Consider writing up your findings as an answer for others to learn from. You can also accept your own answer and grab the points.

Comment: You probably need `--overlap 0` as well. `dzsave` will write tiles with the deepzoom convention by default, which is to have a few rows and columns of pixels shared between neighbouring tiles.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10853119/chop-image-into-tiles-using-vips-command-line/