# PHP picture parts from image (CROP)

Tags: php, image, crop, imagick

Hello i have big technical problem i need crop image to parts like this:

[image]
One parts is 500px x 500px except in the case where there is less space.

Example image size is 1920px x 1080px totaly i have 12 parts of image.

Me problem i have **very big image** it's **30 000px x 20 000px** it's have about **2800part**s.

I try to use php imagemagic library

imagemagic command line codes: `http://www.ioncannon.net/linux/81/5-imagemagick-command-line-examples-part-1/`

with this command i can crop image place: `convert flower.jpg -crop 500×500+0+0 flower_crop.jpg`

first and seconds arguments width height of part: 500;

the third and fourth arguments it's the from the location started clipping;

I tested crop one part per 20 seconds if i need get 2800 parts i need about: `2800 x 20 / 60 / 60 = 15-16~ hours` I need get fastest result. How i can do it..

full php code:

```
public function cutImgIntoPieces($imgPieceSizeWidth, $imgPieceSizeHeight, $outputDir) {
    $pieceWidth = $imgPieceSizeWidth;
    $pieceHeight = $imgPieceSizeHeight;

    $divWidth = floor($this->getImgWidth() / $pieceWidth);
    $modWidth = $this->getImgWidth() % $pieceWidth;
    $divHeight = floor($this->getImgHeight() / $pieceHeight);
    $modHeight = $this->getImgHeight() % $pieceHeight;

    for ($i = 0; $i <= $divWidth; $i++) {
        for ($j = 0; $j <= $divHeight; $j++) {

            $pieceWidth = ($i == $divWidth ? $modWidth : $imgPieceSizeWidth);
            $pieceHeight = ($j == $divHeight ? $modHeight : $imgPieceSizeHeight);

            exec("cd ". $this->getDirName() . " & convert " . $this->getFullFileName() . " -crop " . $pieceWidth . "x" . $pieceHeight . "+" . $imgPieceSizeWidth * $i . "+" . $imgPieceSizeHeight * $j . " " . $i . "_" . $j . ".jpg");

        }
    }
}



    $img->cutImgIntoPieces(500, 500, 'C:/xampp/htdocs/');
```

Comment: You should put your php code. Maybe croping with GD would be faster ? Are you running this on the final server ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [ImageMagick crop huge image](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10542246/imagemagick-crop-huge-image)

Comment: maybe exist other method

Comment: Have you tried the method from the link over ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the command line (on a medium spec iMac) I can achieve what you are trying to do in 2 minutes 44 seconds using the following command:

```
convert -crop 500x500 image.jpg tile%04d.jpg
```

This way you only read the image once and only execute `convert` once, and it works out all the tiles for you, each one 500x500 with names like `tile1799.jpg`.

**Update**

To get it even faster, I did this. First, tile the image into 4 quadrants, called `quad00.jpg`, `quad01.jpg`, `quad02.jpg` and `quad03.jpg` like this - notice the `@` at the end specifying number of tiles rather than size:

```
convert -crop 2x2@ image.jpg quad%02d.jpg
```

Now I can run 4 parallel processes to split the quadrants into 500x500 tiles and keep all my CPU cores busy:

```
#!/bin/bash
convert -crop 500x500 quad00.jpg tile0-%04d.jpg &
convert -crop 500x500 quad01.jpg tile1-%04d.jpg &
convert -crop 500x500 quad02.jpg tile2-%04d.jpg &
convert -crop 500x500 quad03.jpg tile3-%04d.jpg &
wait
```

The splitting the original image into 4 quadrants took 52 seconds, and then splitting all four quadrants into 500x500 tiles in parallel took a further 7 seconds, for a total time of 59 seconds.

In answer to your further question about sizing the inityial 4 quadrants unequally, you are at liberty to do the initial four quadrants however you like - you know your images better than me! In fact, depending on your CPU, you may be better off with 8 initial tiles, or maybe 2. Anyway, you will need to experiment. In order to do that, you can calculate the size (width and height) of your image like this and then do some maths to decide how you want to do the initial quadrants, or halves or whatever:

```
# Get width
w=$(identify -format %w image.jpg)

echo $w
30000

# Get height
h=$(identify -format %h image.jpg)

echo $h
20000
```

Comment: too slow i need get result one crop about one second

Comment: Too funny! I reduce the time by a factor of 900 and your comment is that it is too slow.

Comment: mhmm i understand you croped all 2800 parts per 59 seconds ?

Comment: i test it it's realy nice!!! maybe i can in first step where get four parts "quad00,quad01,quad02,quad03" get not equal four parts like this example: if have 21000px x 20 000px (first part get 10 000px x 10 000px, second 11 000px x 10 000px)

Comment: I have added some tips on how to do that. Please have another look.